# How to delete data in binding table?

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got three tables: A,B and AB. A and B are typical tables, AB - table that binds them. For example:

```
A table
_____________________
int id | varchar data
1       hello


B table
_____________________
int id | varchar data
1       world


AB table
___________________
int a_id | int b_id
1         1
```

A and B have Many-To-Many relation. Sometimes I should remove records from A table. That would be nice to remove binded records from AB too. But how can I do that? This is my effort:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ab", catalog = "mycatalog", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<B> bs= new HashSet<B>(0);
```

And remove method:

```
@Override
    public int remove(int index) {
        Session session = null;
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session
                .createSQLQuery("DELETE FROM mycatalog.A WHERE id=:id").setInteger(
                        "id", index);
        try {
            return query.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from:

[hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/)

**Delete Cascade**

The cascade=”delete” is declared in ‘stockDailyRecords’ to enable the delete cascade effect. When you delete the ‘Stock’, all its reference ‘stockDailyRecords’ will be deleted automatically.

```
<!-- Stock.hbm.xml -->
<set name="stockDailyRecords" cascade="delete" table="stock_daily_record" ...>
      <key>
            <column name="STOCK_ID" not-null="true" />
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="com.mkyong.common.StockDailyRecord" />
</set>
```

Code:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from Stock where stockCode = :stockCode ");
q.setParameter("stockCode", "4715");
Stock stock = (Stock)q.list().get(0);
session.delete(stock);
```

Output:

```
Hibernate: 
    delete from mkyong.stock_daily_record 
    where DAILY_RECORD_ID=?

Hibernate: 
    delete from mkyong.stock 
    where STOCK_ID=?
```